# How is the buffer allocated by gzbuffer used in zlib?

Tags: zlib

Trying to understand how `gzbuffer` is used in zlib. This is cut from the manual (https://www.zlib.net/manual.html):

> ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT gzbuffer OF((gzFile file, unsigned size));
>
> Set the internal buffer size used by this library's functions. The default buffer size is 8192 bytes. This function must be called after gzopen() or gzdopen(), and before any other calls that read or write the file. The buffer memory allocation is always deferred to the first read or write. Three times that size in buffer space is allocated. A larger buffer size of, for example, 64K or 128K bytes will noticeably increase the speed of decompression (reading).
>
> The new buffer size also affects the maximum length for gzprintf().
>
> gzbuffer() returns 0 on success, or –1 on failure, such as being called too late.

So three times the buffer size is allocated. When I call `gzwrite`, is compressed data written to the buffer (compression is done at every call to `gzwrite`) or is uncompressed data written to the buffer? (and compression is then delayed until the buffer is filled and `gzflush` is called internally, or i call `gzflush` myself)

When I continue to call `gzwrite`, what happens when the buffer is filled? Is there some allocation of new buffer memory at this point or is the buffer simply flushed to the file and then re-used?

Comment: `zlib` is free software, so you could study its source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading, a `size` input buffer is allocated, and a `2*size` output buffer is allocated. When writing, the same thing, but reversed.

If `len` is less than `size` in `gzwrite(state, buf, len)`, then the provided data goes into the input buffer. That input buffer is compressed once it has accumulated `size` bytes. If `len` is greater than or equal to `size` what remains in the buffer is compressed, followed by all of the provided `len` data. If a flush is requested, then all of the data in the input buffer is compressed.

Compressed data is accumulated in the `size` output buffer, which is written every time `size` compressed bytes have been accumulated, or when the `gzFile` is flushed or closed.

Comment: I only write (using `gzwrite`) and it looks like the offset is increased by `2*size` at a time. This should also mean the `2*size` of data is compressed right? The compression happens when `gzwrite` is called and not when the buffer is flushed.

Comment: What do you mean by "offset"?